# moveToHDFS file not found in PySpark script

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, hdfs

I have a bit of a strange issue.

When I run this command in terminal, it works and does indeed copy the file to the desired location.

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal concsessions.csv /user/username/spark_exports/
```

But, when I run it as part of my script (below), it doesn't and I get this error - can anyone help me?

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, definitely something!

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from datetime import datetime

#Set the date for the filename
now = datetime.now()
yday  = long(now.strftime('%s')) - 24*60*60

spark = SparkSession\
.builder\
.appName('wap')\
.master('yarn')\
.enableHiveSupport()\
.getOrCreate()

import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

#The below prints your results to your chosen destination (Hive, Stdout, CSV)

print('data load starting...')

cmd = '''select * from db.conc_sessions'''
df1 = spark.sql(cmd)
df1.printSchema()
print('data ingested successfully')

print('setting variables...')

timestart= '2019-10-14 00:00:00'
timeend= '2019-10-14 23:59:59'
time_to_check = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestart, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

iters = 0
session = 0
add = []

print('begin iteration...')
while iters < 96:

    time_to_add = iters * 900
    time_to_checkx = time_to_check + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time_to_add)
    stringtime = time_to_checkx.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

    iters = iters + 1

    spark_date_format = "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
    df1 = df1.withColumn('start_timestamp', F.to_timestamp(df1.start_time, spark_date_format))
    df1 = df1.withColumn('end_timestamp', F.to_timestamp(df1.end_time, spark_date_format))

    filterx = df1.filter( (df1.start_time < time_to_checkx) & (df1.end_time > time_to_checkx ))

    session = filterx.count()
    newrow = [stringtime, session]
    add.append(newrow)

import pandas as pd
output = pd.DataFrame.from_records(add)
output.columns = ['time','count']
output = output.groupby(['time'])[['count']].agg('sum').reset_index()
output.to_csv('concsessions.csv', sep=',')

#copy the CSV from the local server to HDFS
import subprocess
subprocess.call("hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal concsessions.csv /user/username/spark_exports/")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `shell=True` in `subprocess.call`.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh.

Edit your call as below and see.

```
subprocess.call("hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal concsessions.csv /user/username/spark_exports/", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.call(['hdfs',  'dfs',  '-copyFromLocal' , 'concession.csv', 'user/username/spark_exports'])
```